# Save the captured image in application directory in Android

Tags: android

Hello I am working on android application where I require to save the captured image in application directory here `/data/data/package.name/app_data/capturedImage`

So I am creating the directory this

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
File directory = cw.getDir("capturedImage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File file = new File(directory,System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
```

So I am looking for Is there any restriction of a number of images I can save this location `/data/data/package.name/app_data/capturedImage` ? or Any limitation in terms of size of this application directory ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should start with using getFilesDir() and openFileOutput() and put your files there. Futher I do not see that your code creates a directory. There is no limit other then full==full.

Comment: @greenapps OK thank you. Can you write this in the answer with some more explanation so that I can accept your answer.